# Angular ngFor get's data stuck after delete operation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, ngfor

While using ngFor I observed a weird behaviour. I have a table where I build multiple rows using ngFor. And for each row, I have a button for deleting the corresponding row based on an id (not the row id, but the id of the current object from array). At the first deletion, nothing wrong occurs. But when I try to delete another row, the method for row deletion is called two times, once with the correct id but once with the id of the item that was deleted (the row does not appear in the table anymore). Below is the code that I am using:

```
<tr
              *ngFor="let indexValue of indexSummary | sortIndex: type: order | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize; let i = index"
              triggers="click" placement="top-left" [autoClose]="true" ngbTooltip="{{onShowTooltip(indexValue.indexNames)}}">
              <td>{{(i + 1) + (this.pageSize * (this.page - 1))}}</td>
              <td>{{indexValue.chartsResult}}</td>
              <td>{{indexValue.indexResult}}</td>
              <td>{{indexValue.indexNames.length}}</td>
              <td>{{indexValue.creationDate}}</td>
              <td (click)="onGoToReports(indexValue.id, $event)"><i class="far fa-paper-plane pointer"></i></td>
              <td (click)="onDeleteIndexHistory(indexValue.id, $event)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt pointer"></i></td>
```

And the delete method:

```
const summaryPoz = this.indexSummary.findIndex(item => item.id === historyId);
if (summaryPoz !== -1) {
  this.indexSummary.splice(summaryPoz, 1);
```

What can I do to fix this behaviour? (except for page refresh please). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not finding any problem with your code, maybe can be another thing, can you provide more code, please?

Comment: as @GabrielSereno said, your code seems normal. Speaking for myself the only unusual thing is that indexSummary followed by that many pipes. Beside that no clue. Can you show some of the indexSummary array?

Comment: 0: Object { id: 5, chartsResult: "Impaired Fasting Glucose: Prediabetes", indexResult: "-", … }
1: Object { id: 4, chartsResult: "Impaired Fasting Glucose: Prediabetes", indexResult: "-", … }
2: Object { id: 1, chartsResult: "Impaired Fasting Glucose: Prediabetes", indexResult: "-", … }. Basically I delete them by the id of the objects

Comment: With a console.log() in the delete method, I see that is called several times for one click with details that are no longer in the array. I don't know what it can be.